# Remove button residue with overlapping png button-images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two arrows that are both buttons and png images that overlap a scrollbar. The arrows work aside from these two tiny squares that dont seem to move/disappear when I style the arrows. They seem to be empty buttons left over from the arrows. I need the tiny squares to go away, and have tried border: none and background-color: transparent, but these and other css commands only seem to apply to the arrows and not the little boxes at the bottom. Help!

Button html and css:

```
    <button onclick="scrollMe('left')"> <img id="arrowL" src='../static/imj/arrowLeft.png' > </button>
      <button onclick="scrollMe('right')"> <img id="arrowR" src='../static/imj/arrowRight.png'> </button>

#arrowL{
    width: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 812px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#arrowR{
    width: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 657px;
    top: 812px;
    z-index: 3;
}'
```

[The two boxes- whiteish grey below the people scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOOBr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS styles are only applying to the `img` elements as the `ids` are on those elements

To style your buttons, you could use a class like `.arrow-button`, for example

```
<button onclick="scrollMe('left')" class="arrow-button"> <img id="arrowL" src='../static/imj/arrowLeft.png' > </button>
<button onclick="scrollMe('right')" class="arrow-button"> <img id="arrowR" src='../static/imj/arrowRight.png'> </button>

//CSS
.arrow-button {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```